# Previous employer did not inform home office (UK) about my resignation

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

I worked for a company in the UK on Tier 2 (General) work visa which is expiring in 2017. After working for some time I resigned from the job and returned to my country (after one month from last day of working) without waiting for any notice of curtailment from home office.

Now its been more than 1 year since I have left the UK and have got a new job offer from another company. The company is a sponsored employer and when they applied for COS they were told I am still employed under Tier 2 visa, which is not correct. Does this mean my previous employer failed to inform home office that I no longer work for them. How would it affect me if they did not inform ? Will home office refuse my application for new visa ?

Comment: I know this is late, but has the new company actually been refused a COS?

Answer (score 2):

Technically and legally, the onus is on the employer to report this change of situation. As long as you have acted in good faith, there is no reason your application should be refused because of that. That said, if the company cannot acquire a COS, then you can't apply anyway.